# How to convert this for loop to a while loop in C using a continue statement

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to convert the following for-loop

```
for( x = 1; x <= 10; x++ ){

    if( x == 5 ){
        continue;
    }

    printf("%d ", x);

}
```

into a while-loop. However, the following code, which seems reasonable to me, is not executing properly:

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    if( x == 5){
       continue;
    }
    printf("%d ", x);
    x++;
}
```

Why is this the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your for loop is correct? That `x++;` at the end seems to me very suspicious

Comment: @carcigenicate, that was just a typo on my part. I have fixed it now. In the original, I had the if statement. Thanks.

Comment: Your for loop increments x twice each iteration, your while loop does not.

Comment: @Amadeus thanks for pointing that out. That was also a typo.

Comment: Your while loop will never end.  When x == 5 you continue forever since you never increment it. https://ideone.com/B2eLwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your `for` loop in JavaScript so we can run it here and see the output. C and JavaScript have the same loop semantics, so this makes a handy way to test the code:

```js
for( x = 1; x <= 10; x++ ) {

    if( x == 5 ) {
        continue;
    }

    console.log( x );
}
```

Now, why doesn't your `while` loop produce this output? It's because of the `continue` statement. Here's a JavaScript version of your `while` loop:

```
var x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ) {

    if( x == 5) {
       continue;
    }

    console.log( x );

    x++;
}
```

On second thought, don't run that! In fact I took off the `snippet` tag so you don't run it. Because here is the problem...

When you use `continue` in a any kind of loop, it skips the rest of the *loop body*. In the `for` loop, the `x++` is not part of the loop body. It is part of the `for` statement itself, so it gets run even when you use `continue` inside the loop. In the `while` loop, the `x++` is *part of* the loop body, so it gets skipped along with the rest of the body.

Your `while` version will hit an infinite loop when `x` is `5`, because it will not increment `x` during that loop iteration, and in fact will never increment `x` again.

Now for some advice: it is certainly *possible* to write a `while` loop that works like the corrected `for` loop, but it's going to be a bit more complicated. Why do you want to use `while` instead of `for`? Stick with the `for` loop for simplicity, or explain the reason you want to use `while` instead.

In general, you can say that the following `for` loop and `while` loop are equivalent:

```
for( a; b; c ) {
    // loop body
}

a;
while( b ) {
    // loop body
    c;
}
```

But they are not the same when you use `continue` in the loop body, for the reason mentioned above.

If you really want to use `while`, you can use a `goto` as in Amadeus's answer. Or you can rearrange the loop body, like this:

```js
var x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ) {

    if( x != 5) {
        console.log( x );
    }

    x++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response! Yes, the extra increment in the for-loop was an accident. As for why I am trying to use a while-loop to perform this task, I am just fiddling around as I learn C.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop can be seen as compound of:

```
for (initialization; test; increment) 
{
    body
}
```

and can be implemented using while loop keeping this format:

```
initialization;
while (test)
{
    body
    increment;
}
```

So, in your case, the solution is (you are using the continue statement, which means that you have to skip the rest of the body and goes directly to the increment part):

```
x = 1;
while (x <= 10) {
    if( x == 5 ){
        goto cont;
    }

    printf("%d ", x);

    cont: x++; // this increment is due the increment in for statement
}
```

Using goto to jump to skip the body and going to the increment part

Comment: Isn't there an endless loop when x==5 ?

Comment: The trick is when `body` contain a `continue` or `break`.  So not quite like `initialization;
while (test)
{
    body
    increment;
}`

Comment: Instead of a goto, you can use an else.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to C! If you can keep something simpler without compromising efficiency and readability, do that _(^.^)_/ ! i.e.

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    if( x != 5)
        printf("%d ", x);
    x++;
}
```

Notice: You don't even need brackets if you're doing a single command [within that "if" statement).

When you use "continue" *in a while*, you are **skipping the loop's instructions**, and you need 'em in order to iterate! ;)

Comment: Although you don't _need_ braces with a single statement as you illustrated, many of us do not allow them to be omitted in our code. The reason is that it makes it too easy to have a bug like the infamous [`goto fail;`](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) that caused security breaches a few years ago. If you always use the braces you're less likely to have a nasty problem like that one.

Comment: Can you provide some articles explaining/defining that type of security breach, Michael? Sounds interesting!

Comment: Click the "goto fail;" text in my previous comment for an excellent article on the topic. (I wish SO made it more clear when formatted code like this is also a clickable link; it's hard to tell it from the way they display it.) Also do a web search for "goto fail" for several other articles. And a handy tip: if you use the Chrome address bar to do a search that begins with a keyword like "goto" or "google", type a space at the beginning to prevent Chrome from interpreting it as a keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In the second block of code you have

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    for( x == 5){
       continue;
    }
    printf("%d ", x);
    x++;
}
```

and in the second line of the `while` statement, you have `for(x == 5)` instead of `if (x == 5)` like you have in the for-loop in the first block.

Otherwise, this is the correct way to write a for-loop as a while loop, essentially move the initialization variable to outside of the loop, and place the modification statement at the end.  Depending on the situation, one will probably be a better choice than the other, but they are interchangeable.

Edit:

It would probably be best to minimize the code by excluding the one time the value is 5 instead of using `continue` when it isn't.  Additionally, the other poster is correct, your continue statement would exclude the increment of `x` causing an infinite loop.

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    if ( x != 5){
       printf("%d ", x);
    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Indeed, the "for" was a typo and I meant it to be an if, as it is in the original code, but it is not working. I am not getting the output that I should be with the while-loop, 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration (except when X==5) has two iterations, one in the for() and one in the body.  Try something like this:

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    if( x == 5){
      ;
    }else{
        printf("%d ", x);
        x++;
    }
    x++ // "for()" increment
}
```

Comment: Aka `if(x!=5)`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add "else" - what you want to be done if the "if statement" is not working, or you can tell the program what to do in every other case:

```
int x = 1;
while( x <= 10 ){
    if( x != 5)
       printf("%d ", x);
    x++;
}
```

Comment: You still do not reach the `x++` after you reach `continue`. The code is flawed in the same way as from the OP.